# Is it possible to have a string ignore null terminate chars

Tags: c, string, null

I have a function that gets passed an array of chars, or a string. I use this array for data array and thus has a lot of random characters in it including NULL chars. My problem comes in when I am trying to retrieve this data the compiler sees and the Null char and thinks the string ends. Thereby effectively throwing out all the data after that. Is there an option where I can somehow make an array that is not ended by a Null char?

Comment: If you have "lots of NULL chars", then you don't have a string...

Comment: An array or chars and a string are not the same thing.  What do you mean by "retreive data?"  How about showing some code??  Please read here on how to ask questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: The "compiler" isn't your problem. It's your runtime library. When you say the string is clipped when you "retieve" it, what exactly to you mean? What function are you calling to do that? If that function stops on 0 bytes, then don't use that function; use something that doesn't.

Comment: `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a null *pointer* constant. Using that word to refer to the null character is confusing. A string is terminated by the first null, or `'\0'`, character.

Comment: A string is, by definition, "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A C string and an array of `char` is not the same thing. The first is implemented by means of the second with the additional convention that the string ends where the array has the first `0` element.

So what you need is just an `unsigned char[something]` and you'd have to keep track of the length that you want to have separately. Then also you shouldn't use `strcpy` or similar functions but `memcpy` etc.

Answer (score 3):

The null (`'\0'`) terminator is treated as the string terminator in C. So You need to tell the compiler exactly how much data to read, why don't you maintain a separate count for the size of the data and then use functions which use that size to operate on the data?

Comment: Like the C++ string does.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a string in C language is not some sort of "black box" object that can somehow choose to ignore or not ignore something out of its own will. It is based on a mere raw array of chars, of which you have full unrestricted control. This means that it is really *you* who chooses how to process the data stored in that array of chars. Not the compiler, not the string itself, but you and only you.

Secondly, a string in C language is defined as a sequence of characters ending with zero character. This immediately means that if you attempt using string-specific functions with your array, they will always stop at zeros. If you want your data to contain embedded zeros, then you should not call it "strings" and you should not use any string-specific functions with it. So, forget about `strcmp`, `strcpy` and such. Again, it is something you are responsible for, not the compiler.

Thirdly, the functions you would use with such data would typically be functions like `memcpy` for copying, `memcmp` for comparison and so on. Anything that's missing you'll have to implement yourself. And since you no longer have any terminating characters in your data, it is your responsibility to know where the data begins and where it ends.